# Cupy error installation

Tags: chainer

I tried to install cupy via pip install cupy. I get the following error:

```
    Looking in links: 
    /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/custom/python/wheelhouse/avx2, 
   /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/custom/python/wheelhouse/generic Collecting cupy
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/38/14/ddb1a13f77a50d721814e28181ae90e0d57c3f8d4faa9a7b2e028cfcc99a/cupy-4.0.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Options: {'profile': False, 'annotate': False, 'linetrace': False, 'wheel_libs': [], 'package_name': 'cupy', 'no_rpath': False, 'no_cuda': False, 'long_description': None}
    **************************************************
    *** WARNING: nvcc not in path.
    *** WARNING: Please set path to nvcc.
    **************************************************
    **************************************************
    *** WARNING: nvcc path != CUDA_PATH
    *** WARNING: nvcc path: None
    *** WARNING: CUDA_PATH: /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/avx2/Compiler/intel2016.4/cuda/8.0.44
    **************************************************

    -------- Configuring Module: cuda --------
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    gcc: warning: /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/avx2/Compiler/gcc5.4/cuda/8.0.44/include: linker input file unused because linking not done
    /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/avx2/Compiler/gcc5.4/cuda/8.0.44/lib64: file not recognized: Is a directory
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    Cannot build a stub file.
    Original error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1

    ************************************************************
    * CuPy Configuration Summary                               *
    ************************************************************

    Build Environment:
      Include directories: ['/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/avx2/Compiler/intel2016.4/cuda/8.0.44/include']
      Library directories: ['/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/avx2/Compiler/intel2016.4/cuda/8.0.44/lib64']
      nvcc command       : ['/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/avx2/Compiler/intel2016.4/cuda/8.0.44/bin/nvcc']

    Environment Variables:
      CFLAGS          : /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/avx2/Compiler/gcc5.4/cuda/8.0.44/include
      LDFLAGS         : /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/avx2/Compiler/gcc5.4/cuda/8.0.44/lib64
      LIBRARY_PATH    : /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/python/2.7.14/lib:/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/avx2/CUDA/intel2016.4/cuda8.0/openmpi/2.1.1/lib:/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/avx2/Compiler/intel2016.4/cuda/8.0.44/lib64:/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/imkl/11.3.4.258/mkl/lib/intel64:/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/imkl/11.3.4.258/lib/intel64:/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/ifort/2016.4.258/compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.258/linux/compiler/lib/intel64:/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/nix/var/nix/profiles/gcc-5.4.0/lib64:/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/nix/var/nix/profiles/gcc-5.4.0/lib:/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/Core/icc/2016.4.258/compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.258/linux/compiler/lib/intel64:/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/nix/var/nix/profiles/16.09/lib
      CUDA_PATH       : /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2017/avx2/Compiler/intel2016.4/cuda/8.0.44
      NVCC            : (none)

    Modules:
      cuda      : No
        -> Include files not found: ['cublas_v2.h', 'cuda.h', 'cuda_profiler_api.h', 'cuda_runtime.h', 'cufft.h', 'curand.h', 'cusparse.h', 'nvrtc.h', 'nvToolsExt.h']
        -> Check your CFLAGS environment variable.

    ERROR: CUDA could not be found on your system.
    Please refer to the Installation Guide for details:
    https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/install.html

    ************************************************************

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/localscratch/tamouze.7243408.0/pip-install-_wUDId/cupy/setup.py", line 65, in <module>
        ext_modules = cupy_setup_build.get_ext_modules()
      File "cupy_setup_build.py", line 561, in get_ext_modules
        extensions = make_extensions(arg_options, compiler, use_cython)
      File "cupy_setup_build.py", line 374, in make_extensions
        raise Exception('Your CUDA environment is invalid. '
    Exception: Your CUDA environment is invalid. Please check above error log.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /localscratch/tamouze.7243408.0/pip-install-_wUDId/cupy/
```

Im working on SSH linux server. Im not comfortable with linux environment. My problem looks like the environment is not ok, please how can setup correctly them? I want to use cupy with cahiner

Comment: As written in the Error message, ` Your CUDA environment is invalid. Please check above error log.`
Did you installed CUDA correctly?

Another possible way is to use conda. Recently cupy is also released under conda. You can try `conda install cupy`

Comment: @corochann with '''conda install -n testing-env cupy''', the installation is ok. but when running a code i get the following error:/home/tamouze/anaconda2/envs/testing-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cupy/creation/ranges.py:57: UserWarning: Please set the CUDA path to environment variable `CUDA_PATH`
etc....  so please, how can i set the varaibale cuda? im not familiar so much with python and linux

Comment: Did you install CUDA? You need to install it manually before installing cupy I guess.
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-zone

Can you see `/usr/local/cuda` in your environment? Usually after cuda is installed, it is located in this path in linux.

Answer (score 1):

for cuda 9.0:

**pip install --pre cupy-cuda90**

Or you may want to first do:
 1. check you module list : **module list**

2. unload pgi module: **module unload pgi/16.9**